# Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions config file not getting deployed with git aws.push

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've linked a git branch to my Elastic Beanstalk environment and using git aws.push it deploys correctly.

I've now added a `.extensions` directory which contains a config script which should be creating a couple of directories.  However, nothing appears to be happening.

I understand that the `.extensions` directory should be copied across to the ec2 instance as well but I'm not seeing it.

I've checked `eb-tools.log` and it's not mentioned in the upload.

Is there something additional that's required?

The script contains:

```
commands:
  cache:
    command: mkdir /tmp/cache
  items:
    command: mkdir /tmp/cache/items
  chmod:
    command: chmod -R 644 /tmp
```

Comment: Did you check the Elastic Beanstalk log? That should contain what all files are downloaded and all the logs in a consolidated together.

Comment: Did you mean .ebextensions or .extensions? Have you done git add .ebextensions followed by git commit?

Comment: @RohitBanga WOW, thanks. I had added an .ebextensions folder and was going crazy over it being ignored. Was previously using a staged deploy but not anymore, so I totally forgot about the fact that `eb deploy` only creates a git archive from the last *commit*. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the run logs for this at `/var/log/cfn-init.log`.
In here I could see that the `mkdir` commands had worked initially but subsequently failed as the directory already existed. 
Turns out that eb extensions run commands in alphabetical order so I had to change the commands to:

```
01command1:
02command2:
```

etc.
From this point on it worked fine.

Something else that was confusing me is that the .ebextensions directory in my local git repo was not appearing on the target instance directory. this is because once it's been run it will delete the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your local script file has a `.config` extension. I was having a similar problem because my local file was called `.ebextensions/01_stuff.yaml` and it was fixed once I renamed it to `.ebextensions/01_stuff.config`.